# Redirect not working for me

Tags: asp-classic, redirect, isapi

I have the following line in my IsapiRewrite.ini file:

```
RewriteRule ^/test-url.asp$  http://www.google.co.uk/ [R=301,L]
```

But it doesn't do anything...

However, this DOES work:

```
RewriteRule ^/test-url.asp$  /
```

Is it a case of enabling Redirect or something like that? I would have thought that if the IsapiRewrite4.dll is running, the redirect would work?

Please can someone advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out to be the documentation on the Isapi Readme...

To do redirect, its not "RewriteRule", but instead "RedirectRule"... just tried it by chance. Ended up working. However, the above suggestions do work on .htaccess Linux servers.

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (slightly modified to be case insensitive):

```
RewriteRule ^/test-url.asp$  http\://www\.google\.co\.uk/ [I, R=301,L]
```

Comment: hi there, tried that and no luck :(

It's odd. I can use the same line on a linux server using .htaccess and it works fine.

Comment: Maybe the rule should be case insensitive. Try with the following:

RewriteRule ^/test-url.asp$  http\://www\.google\.co\.uk/ [I,R=301,L]